# Error in Selection sort implementation in C

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

the purpose of the excercise I'm currently trying to solve and understand is to create a general purpose selection sort function, namely a sorting function that works for both integers and double data types. The basic algorithm for selection sort was given in the excercise, so all I have to do is extend its usage to more than one types of data. My implementation of the function is the following, which seems to match the author's suggested solution:

```
void selection_sort(void *p, int n, enum data d)
{
    int i,j,pos;

    switch(d)
    {
        case INT:
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                pos=i;

                for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
                {
                    if (((int *)p)[j]<((int *)p)[pos])
                        pos=j;
                }

                swap(&((int *)p)[i], &((int *)p)[pos], d);
            }
            break;

        case DOUBLE:
            for (i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                pos=i;

                for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
                {
                    if (((double *)p)[j]<((double *)p)[pos])
                        pos=j;
                }

                swap(&((double *)p)[i], &((double *)p)[pos], d);
            }
            break;

        default:
            exit(1);
    }   
}
```

My implementaion of the function swap is shown below:

```
    void swap(void *a, void *b, enum data d){

    switch(d)
    {
        case INT:
            *((int *)a) = *((int *)a)+*((int *)b);
            *((int *)b) = *((int *)a)-*((int *)b);
            *((int *)a) = *((int *)a)-*((int *)b);
            break;



        case DOUBLE:

            *((double *)a) = *((double *)a)+*((double *)b);
            *((double *)b) = *((double *)a)-*((double *)b);
            *((double *)a) = *((double *)a)-*((double *)b);
            break;
    } 
}
```

This is where my problem begins. The suggested implementation for the swap function goes like this:

```
    void swap(void *a, void *b, enum data d)
{
    int tempi;
    double tempd;

    switch(d)
    {
        case INT:
            tempi=*(int *)a;
            *(int *)a=*(int *)b;
            *(int *)b=tempi; 
            break; 
        case DOUBLE:
            tempd=*(double *)a;
            *(double *)a=*(double *)b;
            *(double *)b=tempd;             
    }
}
```

which works with the rest of my code, however when I use my implementation of the swap function it spits out errors. In the suggested solution, the author creates a temporary variable for the integer case and one for the double case, which are not both needed at the same time, so in my implementation I had thought about saving some space and optimizing it a bit. My main function is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum data{INT, DOUBLE};

void selection_sort(void *pinakas, int n, enum data d);
void swap(void *a, void *b, enum data d);

int main()
{
  int a[10]={1,4,7,5,6,8,6,2,3,3};
  int i;

  for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
      printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  selection_sort(a, 10, INT);

  for (i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
     printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }

  return 0; 
  }
```

When using the author's function my output looks like this:

```
1 4 7 5 6 8 6 2 3 3
1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7 8
```

However when using my implementation I get the following:

```
1 4 7 5 6 8 6 2 3 3
0 2 3 3 4 5 0 0 0 0
```

and I do not understand why. I've spent quite some time on trying to find the error, worrying that it could possibly be something deeper about pointers that I'm missing right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens in your swap function when it is asked to swap an element with itself?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for pointing this out, I actually missed it, tried with a list of non repeating numbers, but keep getting 0's in the last 4 digits, still can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Normally, when you design a generic array manipulation function in C, you end up with a signature similar to that of `qsort()` or `bsearch()` in standard C.  You get a pointer to the start of the array, the size of each item, the number of items, and a pointer to a function for doing comparisons.  You are not really writing generic code.   Your code can handle either of two types, but it can't also handle arrays of strings, or arrays of structures, or …

Comment: @Summand Your swap algorithm only works if the address of two numbers are different, not their value.In other words, it only works when `arguments` are not same. Also, when the two numbers is very big, `add` will overflow which results in a wrong answer too. And using this methods to swap two numbers, it seems to execute slower than using a temporary variable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler that's a step further but technically it was only required for those 2 data types so I didn't bother going for the more generic approach

Comment: @persuez you're right, I'll look into the sorting algorithm to see for which elements of the array a comparison is made between same arguments